# Finding flow decomposition

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

In Daniel Marcus's Graph Theory - A Problem Oriented Approach:

According to the integral flow decomposition theorem, a flow with value n can be written as the sum of n unit path flows and possibly some cycle flows.

In problem 6, this theorem is supposed to apply in two different ways on the following flow:

[image]

But I can only find the decomposition: UAB + AVC + 2(UABCV)

Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: This is not clear in your question, but in your decomposition, $UAB$ and $AVC$ need to be cycles in order to have a valid decomposition.
The $U-V$ flow is equal to $2$, so the theorem asserts that you can find a decomposition with 2 unit path flows. The only path in your decomposition is  $UABCV$ with a weight of 2, which makes 2 unit path flows, so your decomposition is correct. You can find another decomposition by using the path $UAV$ in your decomposition.

Comment: UAV and which other paths or cycles?

Comment: Once you have removed one unit of $UAV$, you have only one possible path from $U$ to $V$. The remaining flow forms a circulation, which you should be able to break easily in cycles.

Comment: Once $UAV$ has been removed then the only possible path from $U$ to $V$ is $UABCV$. Then we are left with a cycle $AVC$ of weight 1 and edges $BU$ and $AB$ of weights 1. $BU$ and $AB$ aren't cycles.

Comment: Once $UAV$ and $UABCV$ has been removed, there is no more flow on $AV$, so $AVC$ is not a cycle. You have the cycles $CV$, $ABC$ and $UAV$ remaining.

Comment: How are $CV$ and $UAV$ cycles?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $UAB$ instead of $UAV$. $CV$ is a cycle because you remove one unit of flow in the direction $CV$ wit the path $UABCV$ but you still have one unit of flow on both direction of $CV$.

Comment: Thank you, I finally see it.